# why did the if not work?

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement

Hi i was scraping yahoo finance and i wanted the print the stock if it is greater than 50 but i did not work anyway here is the code:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

list = ["aapl","goog"]
i = 0
while i < len(list):
       url = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ list[i] +"&q1=1")
       soup = bs4(url,"html.parser")
       for price in soup.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_l84_" + list[i]}):
              print "something"
               i += 1
       if price > 200:
            print price
```

Comment: your indentation matters it should be indented within for loop

Comment: Can't say without seeing the data but where you print "something" why not print out the value of price so you can see if it has the value you expect.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing indentations on the last two lines, so it is not part of the for-loop. Also, you said greater than 50 but the code says 200.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4

list = ["aapl","goog"]
i = 0
while i < len(list):
       url = urllib2.urlopen("http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s="+ list[i] +"&q1=1")
       soup = bs4(url,"html.parser")
       for price in soup.find(attrs={'id':"yfs_l84_" + list[i]}):
           print "something"
           i += 1
           if price > 50:
               print price
```

Comment: @BeyondPrithvi no problem! welcome to SO, accept and consider upvoting an answer if it worked for you

Comment: so i added a stock "yhoo" which is $30 but it still did not break the code why?

Comment: What do you mean "did not break the code"? It should not print the stock price because you specified to only print if the stock price is greater than 50